# Find and Replace , between 2 characters

Tags: regex, csv, replace, find

So I have a CSV file with some anomaly for eg

```
2019-07-25 00:00:00,1014488,2019-07-25 12:24:12,112629,Amy,Flutmus,84004,GM,0001,2.99,312,FFO & CS PLATE        ||22,10999,90027,90062||Sand w/ Options,1,0,0.2,18.85,0,1
```

i want to replace , between these characters || ||.
So I'm expecting

```
2019-07-25 00:00:00,1014488,2019-07-25 12:24:12,112629,Amy,Flutmus,84004,GM,0001,2.99,312,FFO & CS PLATE           ,22,*10999*90027*90062,Sand w/ Options,1,0,0.2,18.85,0,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `re.sub` to capture all your strings between `||` and then replacing the `,`s with `*`s:

```
import re

value = "2019-07-25 00:00:00,1014488,2019-07-25 12:24:12,112629,Amy,Flutmus,84004,GM,0001,2.99,312,FFO & CS PLATE        ||22,10999,90027,90062||Sand w/ Options,1,0,0.2,18.85,0,1"

pattern = re.compile(r'\|\|(.+)\|\|')

cleaned_value = pattern.sub(lambda match: match.group().replace(",", "*"), value)

print(cleaned_value.replace(r'||', ','))
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for